# Regular Expression which allows only one dot and digits WPF

Tags: regex, wpf

I have a textbox it should only allow only one dot and atleast one digit after the dot.

for eg: 1 and 1.2. If i enter 1. it should take 1.

33.0, 33, 55.23, 55.6,

i tried the following regex but it is not allowing dot.

It should allow only one dot in the textbox along with digits.

Comment: Can you please give more examples/elaborate on the matches you want have with your regex?

Comment: are you sure you need a regex for this? Might `Double.TryParse` fit your needs?

Comment: Textbox should only allow numbers and only one dot(.)

Comment: From your regular expression, it seems that you also want to allow spaces, no?

Comment: Dont want to allow any space

Comment: My question is how restrict more than one dot in the textbox. that is not answered in that link.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that your textbox can only contain a digit, optionally followed by a single period and 1 or more digits, use:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

To also allow for an optional trailing or leading space, use:

```
^ ?\d+(\.\d+)? ?$
```

Comment: And what about `23.65` ? Add a quantifier after the first `\d`, like `\d+`.

Comment: Regex regex = new Regex("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$");
Its not allowing dot.

Comment: private void _textBoxPreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$"); 
            e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
        }

Comment: @Geeth I'm sorry, but I can't test in wpf. The regex provided will match `1`, `1.2`,`33.0`, `33`, `55.23` and `55.6`. Do you need it to match just `.`?